# Fitting the full File path in a label in one line by showing dots instead of some part of file path Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, label

[image]

Hi Guys, I have searched for different methods for this thing but couldn't get it right. Used AutoEllipses Property, Set the MaximumSize too but to no avail. How can i get a label to show the name of the file being scanned like in the pic i attached? I mean, the label should show some part from the beginning of full path of the file then some dots and then the file name with extension.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to have that done automatically.  You'd have to determine the amount of space available and then construct the string yourself.

Comment: i had a feeling but then i thought asking the experienced ones. :) Should i use the StringBuilder class?

Comment: I don't really see a `StringBuilder` helping here because you're not going to be appending multiple substrings.  Someone else may have a better idea but the way I see this working that you measure the width of the file name with a preceding slash and you also measure successively shorter folder paths with a succeeding ellipsis and then, as soon as you find a sum that fits within the available space, you concatenate those two substrings and display the result.

Comment: Let me do that and then i will up vote you if it succeeds. :)

Comment: you will have to code a failsafe as well because sometimes even just the file name be too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this problem here [Shorten The File Path](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18319/Use-the-NET-framework-to-shorten-a-path-string-wit) and it's a very short solution as far as code is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider a few things; however, the range of possibilities is too large to cover, here.

There are three (3) things you need to know in order to code this properly: the actual [measured size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx) of the filepath string you are sending to the label; the measured size of the label; and the length (in characters) of your file name. There may be a fancy function that reduces the number of things you need to do and know; however, I am not about to read oodles of documentation.

All of the above things need to be dynamic so that your label can take different `String` objects and render them, properly.

```
Dim filePath As String = ""
Dim FileDirectory As String = ""
Dim fileName As String = ""
Dim filePathLength As SizeF = 0.0
Dim labelLength As Double = 0.0
Dim fileNameLength As Integer = 0.0


' Come up with a way for measuring your string: 
Dim _GraphicsUnit As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()

' Receive your file path, here:
' and work with your file path-related Strings:
filePath = ' SOMETHING
fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
fileNameLength = fileName.Length()

' Measure the length of you path
filePathLength = _GraphicsUnit.MeasureString(filePath, INSERTFONT) * _GraphicsUnit.Inches 'or other usable unit


If filePathLength > SIZEOFLABEL Then

    While filePathLength > SIZEOFLABEL

        ' Grab a substring of the the fileDirecory, append the "...", and keep measuring until shorter
        ' than SIZEOFLABEL.
        ' Your algorithm will need to figure out how and when to re-append the fileName

    End While

End If
```

**The above is pseudo-code and is rife with errors.** The above is means to demonstrate some of the tools .Net can provide you, here namely the `GraphicsUnit` [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `Path.` [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path(v=vs.110).aspx). Both of those are helpful. You will essentially be juggling those two 'things' and the `SubString()` method.

My attempt is to show you how to begin to think about the problem you have in front of you so that you can begin to tackle the problem (because as the comments above state, there isn't much out there that will do what you need). Your initial question does not provide any original code on which to base the above pseudo-code; in other words, I don't feel like coding your whole project but at least want to get the answers ball rolling.

### An Additional Thought: .MaxLength

The above approach is quite memory intensive - requiring a lot of repetition that may not be be necessary. Simply knowing the size - in this case the `MaxLength` property - might be helpful. Setting the `.MaxLength` property of the `TextBox` will allow you to know how many characters can fit in the box (you'd need to consider a few other elements, e.g. font, size, etc.).

Knowing this number, you could avoid looping altogether:

SubString of `fileDirectory` equal to the length of `.MaxLength` property, remove number of characters equating to size of `fileName` and "..." and append the latter two.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input, its something to carry on working. I am scanning the files with a recursive function so i already have values for the variables you mentioned, just need to use them now.

Comment: I had a bit more in the `While` loop earlier, but then realized the algorithm was a bit more complicated than my 8:00 PM at night brain could handle :-). The comments on your question, though, seem to have gotten you in the right direction.

Comment: well its 4:30 in the morning here. :) We programers dont sleep. :D And yes, You people have showed me the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PathCompactPathExW` pInvoke method to accomplish this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Program
    <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint:="PathCompactPathExW", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Shared Function PathCompactPathEx(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> pszOut As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> pszSrc As String, _
                cchMax As UInteger, _
                reserved As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Dim longPath As String = "c:\a\very\very\long\path\that\needs\to\be\shortened\by\calling\the\PathCompactpathEx.ext"
        Dim length As Integer = 40

        Dim result As String = CompactPath(longPath, length)

        'Prints c:\a\very\very\...\PathCompactpathEx.ext
        Console.WriteLine(result)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function CompactPath(longPathName As String, wantedLength As Integer) As String
        'NOTE: You need to create the builder with the required capacity before calling function.
        'See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(wantedLength + 1)
        PathCompactPathEx(sb, longPathName, CUInt(wantedLength + 1), 0)
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```